# Which muslim scholars say abrogation is not unique to Quran?

Tags: quran, jews, torah, naskh

According to this article, it seems at least a scholar hold the belief that Jews also had abrogations in their Torah, but they denied it:

> **Jews used to condemn abrogation and claim that it was not permissible, even though it was referred to in the Torah**; thus their rejection of it constituted disbelief and was based on pure whims and desires.
>
> Tafseer **as-Sa‘di, p. 61**
>
> Reference: https://islamqa.info/en/105746

**Question:** Are there any other scholars who say abrogation is not unique characteristic of Quran but also of other revelations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62953/discussion-between-alp-sankhya-and-kilise).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if its upto scholarly opinion.

*Abrogation is when one revealed command is replaced by another, so the first one is no longer acted upon (it was meant for a specific period to address a certain issue) and the second one is to be acted upon.*

Its in the Quran that through Jesus, Allah abrogated some of the prohibitions of the Torah:

> [Quran 3:50](https://quran.com/3/50) And [I have come] confirming what was before me of the
>   Torah and **to make lawful for you some of what was forbidden to you**.
>   And I have come to you with a sign from your Lord, so fear Allah and
>   obey me.

Regarding abrogation mentioned within the Torah, the following examples are given in [Tafsir Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya106.html):

1. To Noah and his people, every creature was made lawful to eat:

   > [Genesis 9:3-4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%209%3A3-4&version=NIV) Everything that lives and moves about will be food
   >   for you. Just as I gave you the green plants, I now give you
   >   everything. “But you must not eat meat that has its lifeblood still in
   >   it.

   But to the Israelites, in the law, only some animals were permitted ( [Quran 4:160](https://quran.com/4/160) and [Quran 6:146](https://quran.com/6/146) ):

   > [Deutronomy 14:6-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2014%3A6-9&version=NIV) You may eat any animal that has a divided hoof and
   >   that chews the cud. However, of those that chew the cud or that have a
   >   divided hoof you may not eat the camel, the rabbit or the hyrax.
   >   Although they chew the cud, they do not have a divided hoof; they are
   >   ceremonially unclean for you. The pig is also unclean; although it has
   >   a divided hoof, it does not chew the cud. You are not to eat their
   >   meat or touch their carcasses. Of all the creatures living in the
   >   water, you may eat any that has fins and scales.
2. Abraham was commanded to sacrifice his son ([Quran 37:102](https://quran.com/37/102)):

   > [Geneisis 22:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%2022%3A2&version=NIV) Then God said, “Take your son, your only son, whom you love—Isaac—and
   >   go to the region of Moriah. Sacrifice him there as a burnt offering on
   >   a mountain I will show you.

   Then to not do it ([Quran 37:104-107](https://quran.com/37/104-107)):

   > [Genesis 22:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%2022%3A12&version=NIV) “Do not lay a hand on the boy,” he said. “Do not do anything to him. Now I know that you fear God, because you have not withheld from me your son, your only son.”
3. The Israelites were commanded to kill each other as punishment for the golden-calf ([Quran 2:54](https://quran.com/2/54)):

   > [Exodus 32:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2032%20%3A%2027&version=NIV) Each man strap a sword to his side. Go back and
   >   forth through the camp from one end to the other, each killing his
   >   brother and friend and neighbor.

   Then Allah forgave them, and the *muhkam* command of the Torah is ([Quran 5:32](https://quran.com/5/32) and [Quran 5:45](https://quran.com/5/45)):

   > [Exodus 20:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2020:13&version=NIV) You shall not murder.